# Firefox ignoring slide animation

Tags: html, css

I've made a slider of sorts, which works as expected on chrome. However, only half of it works on Firefox.

There are 2 animations involved, a fadein effect, and a slidein effect. Only the fadein effect is displayed in firefox.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img class='photo'  src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8320/8035372009_7075c719d9.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo'  src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8517/8562729616_35b1384aa1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{background:#202133;}
.container{
  margin:50px auto;
  width:700px;
  height:485px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.container img{
  width:700px;
  height:485px;
}
.photo{
  position:absolute;
  animation:round 6s infinite;
  opacity:1;
}
@keyframes round{
  0%{
    left: -1000px;opacity:0.5;z-index:1000;
  }
  50%{
    left: 0px; opacity:1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes round{
  0%{
    left: -1000px;opacity:0.5;z-index:1000;
  }
  50%{
    left: 0px; opacity:1;
  }
}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:0s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:3s;}
```

Any idea why?

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HDKBG)

Comment: Set the `opacity` and `left` to `0` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ubvqA

Comment: @Mr.Alien that works, but it blacks out the previous photo while the next one is sliding. Also, do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the left value in your `photo` class:

```
.photo{
  position:absolute;
  animation:round 6s infinite;
  opacity:1;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgFhd)

Also, you should use every vendor prefixes, not just the `-webkit`!

Comment: Close enough. It seems that I would need to set z-index to 0 as well, such that the animation is seamless. If you add that to the answer, i'll accept it when i can.

Comment: Right, forgot that, I just added it to my answer and the codepen.